# php get timestamp from string when i know the format

Tags: php, date, timestamp, date-format

Is there a php func that does this:

```
$timestamp = get_timestamp_from_str('d/m/Y H:i', '10/10/2012 10:10');
```

strtotime() will use the USA version for '10/10/2012' wich is m/d/Y, but i have the day first.

For a particular case i can make my own parser, but the date format can change depending on the visitors local settings. However, i will always know the current format.

I had to insert this last paragraph so that this question is long and good enough for this portals question quality filter

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

You would use it as:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y H:i', '10/10/2012 10:10', new DateTimeZone('Something'));
$timestamp = $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

Just make sure your timezone string is in [the list of supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).